# Why Android save all files in pdf format?

Tags: android

I have a website which allows users to download documents. On PCs, files of different formats, doc, docx, jpg can all be properly downloaded. But why i click the same button on my android tablet or phone, all files will be converted in .pdf format when they are being downloaded.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Are you setting the correct mime type?

Comment: Its working fine on PC yet...

Comment: @answerguy I hope you realize by now that PC and Android behave differently when determining how to launch a file. Windows will use the file extension to figure it out. Android will completely ignore the file extension and use the mime type. So if you have an improper mime type, it will not work on Android.